# Please help me solving Null Pointer Exception in Android?

Tags: android

```
public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
                            waitingDialog.dismiss();
                            User user = response.body();
                                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(user.getError_msg())) {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User has been registered successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    //start new activity.
                                }
                        }
```

//And logcat is: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.asus.drinksdeliverysystem.Model.User.getError_msg()' on a null object reference

Comment: Your response body is null.

Comment: response.body() may be null or contains the response which is not the match with the User model.

Comment: add user.getError_msg()!=null in your if condition

Comment: Did not work at all...